# Add a dynamic height in pixels to a div for smooth slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I need to make a slideToggle menu bar for a responsive layout which is put together using percent width instead of pixels. The slideToggle is jumpy for this reason. Is there a better alternative or a dynamic method of adding a dynamic height (in pixels) to a div?

Here is the simple script I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navicon').click(function(){
  $('.nav').slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("show"); return false;

  });
});


<a class="navicon" href="#">MENU</a>

<div class="nav">
<ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
   <li>E</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

`.nav` cannot have a fixed height, as the site is responsive and the width is set as a percentage

Answer (score 0):

I love sliding and hate its pixel-dependancy. Here's my solution:

Let nav be whatever height you like.

CSS

```
div#nav { height:auto; }
```

Find the pixel height, and use jQ to change your css accordingly.

jQ

```
var div = $("#nav").height();
$('#nav').css('height', div);
$('#nav').slideToggle("slow");
```

if you're worried people will use your slider, THEN change the page height, you can switch the height back to a percentage after the slide is complete.

jQ

```
$('#nav').css('height', '50%');
```